# how to mock session object and response in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-requests

I have method which uses requests to download content from the url in a document. Below is the test case

```
@patch.object(Session, 'get')
def test_download_success(mock_req_get):
    inputDocument = {"contentUri": "http://test"}
    def res():
        r = requests.Response()
        r.status_code = 200
        r.text = "test"
        return r
    mock_req_get.return_value = res()
    output = download(inputDocument)
    assert output["rawContent"] == "test"
```

I am trying to mock the requests session and the get return value but the unittest is not working and it shows an exception at the line

```
mock_req_get.return_value = res()


def download(document):
    queryConnectTimeoutSecond = 5
    queryReadTimeoutSecond = 5
    url = document['contentUri']
    adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=3)
    session = requests.Session()
    session.mount(url, adapter)
    try:
        result = session.get(url, timeout=(queryConnectTimeoutSecond, queryReadTimeoutSecond))
        document["rawContent"] = result.text
    except Exception as err:
        logger.error(f"An error ocurred: {err}")
        document["error"] = {
            "code": 500,
            "message": "Internal Server Error",
            "details": ["Document Crawler Failed"]
        }
    return document
```

I am a complete noob in python programming. Trying to understand if this is the right way to write unittests.

Comment: I personally use the [requests-mock](https://pypi.org/project/requests-mock/) library for that.

Comment: @KlausD. could you please share any examples